# How to replace the copper connector under the bathroom faucet

Tags: bathroom, faucet, sink, copper, epoxy

Trying to use the most accurate description: it's a copper connector or supply line that connects directly to the faucet that breaks with a huge hole. It leaks if I turn on the water.

- photo 1 shows the faucet
- photo 2 shows the underlying connection of the faucet and the copper connector
- photo 3 shows the hole on the pipe

I searched and looks like epoxy is usually used for such situation - is that the only way? The hole is pretty big, also the line is very twisted, not sure if it affects water pressure even if I fixed the hole. I guess it would be great if I can replace it, but I didn't find anyway to detach it from faucet - the connection is deep and I don't have access to it.

[image: photo 1]

[image: photo 2]

[image: photo 3]

Comment: I've gotta ask - what in the world happened that caused that damage?? That's not the kind of thing that happens by throwing the toilet brush under the sink with too much vigor. I don't see anything that looks like marks from pliers that were crushing it. Was someone trying to tighten a fitting and didn't hold the brass nut before twisting the flexible hose fitting?

Comment: I honestly don't know - I'd guess it's a lousy plumber the previous owner hired.

Answer (score 2):

Forget about epoxy for fixing that. The pipe is too damaged and being crushed in like that will definitely affect water pressure out of the faucet.

You're looking at cutting out the bad section and using compression fittings or sweating in a new section of pipe or just connecting the to ends after removing the damaged area.  Trying to do this under the sink would be a pain. I'd remove the faucet and do repairs, then reinstall the faucet.

You might even think about just replacing the faucet if the fixing part worries you.

Comment: +1 Yes, those lines are integral to the faucet and can't be replaced. You need to cut above the damage as @JACK says, then fix a connector by solder or compression fitting. Slopping epoxy on it will not work.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like 1/4 inch soft copper.  Uninstall the faucet and take it out of the counter so you can get a better look and work easily.  Looks like the original fitting was braised on with a torch so you can re use it.  Get a torch and plumber's solder as well as sandpaper and flux.  Use a hacksaw or plumbing pipe cutter to carefully cut the pipe off where it is still straight and round.  If you use a hacksaw, 32tpi blade and cut as straight as you can.  File or ream the edge clean after.  Leave as much pipe as you can.  Heat the fitting with a torch while you have someone pull it apart with two pairs of pliers (don't damage the threads) use fine sandpaper to clean the outside of the pipe where it will be soldered back on.  Treat the outside of the pipe and inside of the fitting with flux.  Preheat the fitting quite hot.  Preheat the pipe at the tip (it may contact plastic parts so the goal is to get it less hot overall.  Place the fitting on the pipe, heat and solder (once the fitting is hot enough to wick the solder, the solder will vanish into the crack where you touch it with the tip of the solder roll.  As soon as this happens you feed solder into the crack all the way around, heating as necessary.  Once it begins, this part should be quite fast.  Watch a few Youtube videos on sweating copper pipe to get some confidence too.  If the cut off pipe is very close to plastic, Consider protecting it with welding heat sink putty.  As soon as you have a good weld take the heat off and allow it to cool.

As another option that doesn't get you a torch, you could be boring and search the internets for a 1/4" compression to male faucet thread fitting, but a common part called a faucet adaptor for attaching a hose to a sink faucet makes it difficult to find the threading you would need.  Compression and quick connect fittings won't risk heating up plastic, but if you can't find the name of that part, you may end up replacing the valve and the pipe to it, which could cost more than a new faucet.

Actually there's one more option.  Get a 1/4" to 1/4" compression fitting and a piece of 1/4" soft to make up the missing length.  You can braise the fitting on to the new piece separately and then put it together with the compression fitting.

Especially recently, some faucets seem hilariously expensive, so I'd probably try to fix it too.

Edit the sticker allows me to clearly see there is enough straight pipe to reconnect it with a compression fitting.  If you want to learn the joys of using a hacksaw blade upside down and bare handed, you can probably even do it without removing the faucet.  That said, just remove the faucet, it's super easy.  Once you have the faucet off, cut the nasty section out of the pipe, remove the sticker and clean off any residue, and connect the pieces together with a compression fitting.  Reinstall the faucet on the countertop and reconnect the hoses.  Those hoses have rubber gaskets and don't need to be done up that hard, so again, when you do up compression fittings, hold the other piece with a separate wrench/pliers.  If the rubber gaskets don't seal from being overcompressed for so long, you can replace them cheaply.

Comment: How to uninstall the faucet though? I didn't find any screws to remove it - seems it just glues to the counter

Comment: See that W shaped metal plate in the photo?  That's a retainer to hold the faucet down and the round thing center appears to be a set screw.  Use two pairs of water pump pliers and wrenches when you undo the feed pipes so you don't twist the soft copper like the first potato did.  Those fittings may be done up rather hard if he wrecked the tube that badly so be careful undoing them.  If that's not a screw, take us a few better pictures of the retaining clip.

Comment: On the top if it's caulked it should only be caulked on the outside edge so you should be able to pre cut the caulk with a razor knife.

Comment: Sigh all these sounds advanced to me. Meanwhile, I was thinking swapping the 2 supply lines (one hot one cold) so we can get hot water (the damaged one is the hot one), is that a good idea? From what I can tell those 2 lines look the same

Comment: Braising is a bit challenging, but materials probably cost less than a new faucet like that one.  If there's enough straight pipe coming out of the fitting, you may even be able to get away with just a compression fitting.  Don't be intimidated.  Faucet repair and replacement is super easy other than braising.  Righty tighty lefty loosey.

Comment: Yeah there's totally enough pipe there for a compression fitting.  Editing my answer.

Comment: I see. How about swapping at the moment?

Comment: Wow. Just go to the plumbing department of local hardware store and ask for: a mini hack saw, a 1/4" brass or push on compression fitting. Cut copper tubing (that is not a pipe) as described above. Reconnect ends of tubing. Done. Normally I fix everything 5x before j throw it out. However, in this case you cannot replace the manufacturer's copper supply tubing and even if you did, as described above, it may not result in a length you need. If the splice i suggest doesn't work, just replace the faucet. If you need further help with the compression fitting, i stsnd by to help.

Comment: I got a bit lost. Are you suggesting that the OP attempt to completely remove that supply line from the fixture and replace it, or that he should cut it off and put a replacement screw-on fitting above the damaged section? If you're suggesting the former, I'd imagine that would be rather difficult and would take a reasonably skilled & experienced plumber, especially since there are often plastic parts inside faucets. If the latter, I'd agree 100%.

Comment: @FreeMan replacing the pipe going into the fixture is probably too difficult, but cutting out the bad section of pipe and resoldering or reattaching the fitting is reasonable, especially since it looks like he has enough straight pipe on both pieces to use a compression fitting and forego solder.  1/4" compression fittings are easy to find, but the 1/4" to male faucet adapter seems hard to locate.

Comment: I would agree with your assessment about replacing the pipe going into the fixture. Unfortunately, as I read your description, I wasn't sure which method you were describing. I would invite you to take a look at some of the list formatting options available in the SE editor - they can make listings of instruction steps much easier and much more readable, helping to eliminate confusion.